# Windows cmd console stops printing

Tags: python, windows, cmd

When I click in the console window, a printing python code snippet paused, if I press a key such as Enter, it continues to print. This makes my GUI program which also print something in the console unresponsive, then I have to press a key in that console. How to fix it?

```
import time
import random

running = True
while running:
    try:
        r = random.randint(1, 100)
        print 'hello %s' % r
        time.sleep(2)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        running = False
```

Comment: I think this is by design because your console window is running in [QuickEdit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/09/13/4886108.aspx) mode.

Comment: You're welcome. Re: your answer, it's on the right path but I believe adding explanations, either in plain text or in code comments, would increase its value. (I would also suggest you aim to restore the previous console mode in *all* exceptional situations, not only `KeyboardInterrupt`).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import time
import random
import ctypes


win32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
hin = win32.GetStdHandle(-10)
mode = ctypes.c_int(0)
win32.GetConsoleMode(hin, ctypes.byref(mode))
old_mode = mode.value
# disable Windows console(cmd.exe) quick edit mode
new_mode = old_mode & (~0x0040)
win32.SetConsoleMode(hin, new_mode)


running = True
while running:
    try:
        r = random.randint(1, 100)
        print 'hello %s' % r
        time.sleep(1)
    except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt):
        win32.SetConsoleMode(hin, old_mode)
        running = False
```